# Retrieve XML attribute value using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have been tasked with building an XSLT file using a specific set of XML. The only problem is I have never used XSLT or XML. I have been digging through it for the last few hours and have hit my first real roadblock.

I need to return or print a value based on a given attribute in a specific XML node.

XML:

```
<Numbers>
    <Products productCode="RSD">
        <Value>54.99</Value>
        <Value>12.35</Value>
        <Value>8.00</Value>
        <Value>9.99</Value>
    </Products>
</Numbers>
```

I need my XSLT transform to produce a heading based on the productCode attribute *(so that it can be placed in a table for better legibility)*. I am a JavaScript developer so in essence I am looking for the equivalent of

```
if(productCode === "RSD"){
    this.html("Product Heading");
}
```

I am completely out of my comfort zone here so any tips/pointers/advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: What do you plan to do with the values? Place them in a table?

Comment: Yes, I plan on placing them in a table. The goal is to make our feed more legible.

Comment: I provided an example. You might be able to use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply your source XML to this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Products[@productCode='RSD']">
        <h1>Product Heading</h1>
        <table border='1'>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Value"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Value">
        <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will generate this HTML fragment:

```
<h1>Product Heading</h1>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>54.99</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>12.35</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>8.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>9.99</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The first template uses an XPath expression to match the nodes you are interested in. The contents of the template describe the structure of your result tree. `<xsl:apply-templates/>` recursively processes the rest of the tree, and if it finds any matching templates it will process them. It uses a *relative* XPath expression `Value` to select the nodes named `<Value>` *in the current context* (which is `<Product>`), and will process all four of them. The second template matches that selection and generates the `<tr><td>` nodes. `<xsl:value-of>` simply prints the *string-value* of the nodes (the XPath expression `.` selects the node in the *current* context, which in the second template is `<Value>`.

You can verify and experiment with your example in this **[Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/gWcDMev)**

Comment: This is fantastic and is a huge help in the right direction. I imagine I will run into one or two more snags along the way so I may post a few more comments on here as the day goes by. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Question: How do I format-number on the XPath expression "."?

Right now I am attempting to convert the values to a percentage so that 54.99 becomes 59.44%. I have attempted to use: 

<tr><td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(.,"%")"/></td></tr>

Comment: If you just need to add the `%` you can simply place it as text, outside the `select`: `<td><xsl:value-of select="."/>%</td>`. You can use `format-number` to control the number of digits after the decimal point, and to multiply it by 100 (if you include a % inside it), but your data is already formatted, so it's not necessary.

Comment: Ah of course how simple.. I have clearly been looking at this too long.

Comment: Question: 

Some of my XML has nodes with data in the attributes such as  
    '<term length="9"></term>'

Is there a way to print out the value of attribute such as '<xsl:value-of select="term[@length]"/>'

Thanks for you help so far.

Comment: `term[@length]` prints the value of all the `term` elements in the current context that have a `length` attribute (containing any value). `term/@length` prints the value of the `length` attribute of the first `term` element in the context (if there is only one, it's what you want; if there are many elements in the context, and you want to select attributes from the others as well, you can use `term[1]/@length`, `term[2]/@length`, etc.

Comment: This has been invaluable in helping me understand context and pathing in XML/XSL. Thank you again.